# sum fouth field data present between patterns in unix

Tags: text-processing, awk

suppose my data is :

```
*dnet *1234 1.2 
1 port *12 2.3  
3 port1 *34 0.2 
7 *15 0.1 
*dnet *234 0.2 
2 *12 0.1 
4 *123 *234 1.2
```

fields are separated by space.

In this I want to get the sum of 4th fields of data present inside each `*dnet`. Some fields have 4th field data some has not. I want 4th field sum value for each `*dnet` seperate.

I tried using `awk` but could not get. It will be thankful if someone helps.

the output for above will look like

*dnet *1234 1.2 2.5

*dnet *234 0.2 1.2

Comment: Please share the data as text or we can't test our solutions against anything. Also, it's unclear where the 0, 1, 6 and 9 comes from in your data set as there is no 4th field that contains that data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/dnet/{if (NR>1) print dnet, sum+0; dnet=$0; sum=0} {sum+=$4} END{print dnet, sum+0}' file
*dnet *1234 1.2  2.5
*dnet *234 0.2  1.2
```

Comment: @VIKASCHOUDHARY please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next,

Comment: @VIKASCHOUDHARY I'm not sure if you're trying to clarify the answer, the question, or ask a new question. Since Ed has appeared to answer your original question, the right thing to do would be to accept this answer. If you have a different question, please ask it separately. If I've misunderstood, please clarify. Thank you!

Comment: @EdMorton Thankyou Sir , it worked

Comment: You're welcome. Again, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.